# Prestashop: how to define multiple primary keys with ObjectModel

Tags: mysql, primary-key, prestashop, composite-primary-key, object-model

I'm defining new entities extending ObjectModel. I've got a table with 2 primary keys like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `ec_product_order_attachment` (
  `id_product` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_order_attachment` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_product`,`id_order_attachment`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

It seems, though, I cannot define a table with 2 primary keys in ObjectModel.

Do you know any way of doing it?

UPDATE (SOLVED)

User PrestaShop-Developer.com gave me a good suggestion. I reworked the Order_Attachment custom entity class, and it's working just fine. So just for documenting, I copy-paste my finished class. Just to say, I made this class for a custom module which adds a tab to the admin edit product page, to add the capability to save special attachments that will be sent along with the order complete mail. So I needed 2 new tables: order_attachment and product_order_attachment to link products to special order_attachments.

```
class Order_Attachment extends ObjectModel{
    public $name;
    public $mime;
    public $attachment_type;
    public $id_order_attachment;

    //validation options are from Prestashop's Validate class
    public static $definition = array(
        'table' => 'order_attachment',
        'primary' => 'id_order_attachment',
        'multilang' => FALSE,
        'fields' => array(
            'name' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'size' => 128),
            'mime' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'size' => 128),
            'attachment_type' =>  array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'size' => 128)
        )
    );

    //get current order attachments for a specific product
    public static function get_product_order_attachments($id_product = false){

        $id_p = ($id_product) ? $id_product : Tools::getValue('id_product');

        $db = Db::getInstance();
        $sql = 'SELECT *
                FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'order_attachment oa
                INNER JOIN ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product_order_attachment poa ON oa.id_order_attachment = poa.id_order_attachment
                WHERE poa.id_product = ' . $id_p;
        return $db->executeS($sql);
    }

    public function save($null_values = false, $autodate = true){

        $result1 = parent::save();

        $result2 = Db::getInstance()->insert('product_order_attachment',array(
            'id_product' => Tools::getValue('id_product'),
            'id_order_attachment' => $this->id
        ));

        return ($result1 && $result2);
    }

    public function delete($id_product = false){

        $id_p = ($id_product) ? $id_product : Tools::getValue('id_product');

        //destroy file associated with the attachment
        if(file_exists(_PS_UPLOAD_DIR_ . $this->name)) unlink(_PS_UPLOAD_DIR_ . $this->name);

        parent::delete();
        Db::getInstance()->delete('product_order_attachment','id_product = ' . $id_p . ' AND id_order_attachment = ' . $this->id);
    }

}//END CLASS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to define multiple-column key within the PrestaShop ObjectModel. This is wrong by definition. Your ObjectModels should be a standalone entities.

Managing this table can be done:

1. Within your OrderAttachment ObjectModel (if you have such)
2. Withing Product ObjectModel (using overrides, adding required methods)
3. You can have ProductOrderAttachment class (not ObjectModel) and
   there to have static methods.

Still, if you have OrderAttachment entity, 1) is the best approach. If you do not have, you may consider adding it, since it seems like "standalone entity".

Comment: Ok thank you. Yes I already have an OrderAttachment class and using it but managed the product_order_arrachment table directly in my custom module via DB class. Didn't think of using it in OrderAttachment, but you're definitely right: cleaner and less error-prone. Thank you!